# "plugin-api-version" keeps on changing between composer installs on different environments

Tags: php, composer-php

We are working with multiple people on a project which uses composer packages. Every time a colleague updates/installs a package, the `plugin-api-version` changes in the `composer.lock` file.

Is this a problem or can we ignore this as long as there are no packages specifying a `plugin-api-version`?

Answer (score 8):

It's a problem when it becomes a problem.

If it doesn't block you from installing your project, then it's not a problem.

But if multiple developers are working on the same project, and all of them are making changes on dependencies (e.g. running `update` and/or `require` calls on that project), the better practice would be for all developers to be on the same version (and hopefully not on V1).

Comment: The better practice, so we define `plugin-api-version` in the `composer.json`?

Comment: It's usually not necessary to do it. It's simply a matter of communication among developers. And again, this is only a problem **if it's a problem**. If it's not, and new packages can be added and updates can be performed, then it's simply not a concern. If one *were* to set this on `composer.json`, it would mean adding to `require` something like `"composer-plugin-api": "^2"`.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because people have different versions of composer in their environments.

Since 2020 ([Version 1.10.0](https://getcomposer.org/changelog/1.10.0)) `composer.lock` has the field `plugin-api-version` to track which Composer version created it.

I recommended all devs to work with the same version of Composer of the production environment, to avoid surprises on deploy.

You can upgrade/rollback versions by running `sudo composer self-update <version>` or downloading the appropriate `composer.phar` file from the *"Manual Download"* section of [Composer downloads page](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

If developers prefer to have and manage their own versions of composer, you may want to download `composer.phar` and make it part of the project. This way, you ensure the same composer is used across all environments on a per-project basis.

Comment: Yeah but when with larger & dynamic teams and different environments this can be a pita to enforce...